# Why is my algebraic expression giving no error and is not getting a value in the decision variables?

Tags: cplex, opl

I'm currently working on implementing a SLRG (Shared Risk Link Group) in a communication infrastructure designed to handle critical information.
To do that I'm implementing a Minimum-Cost SRLG Diverse Routing Problem Algorithm. The algorithm is as follows:

**min** c*(x1+x2)

such that

A*xi=u, i=1,2  **(1)**

H*xi <= 41*zi, i=1,2  **(2)**

z1+z2 <=1  **(3)**

---

**A** is a **30x41** matrix;

**xi** is a decision variable and a **41x1** vector;

**H** is a **2x41** matrix;

**z** is a decision variable and a **2x1** vector;

**c** is a **41x1** vector;

**u** is a **30x1** vector.

All variables are **binary** including the decision variables

What I did was basically trying to implement the code which compiled fine but in the end the decision variables hold no value whatsoever.

```
dvar boolean x1[1..41]; //decision variable of path 1
dvar boolean x2[1..41]; //decision variable of path 2
dvar boolean z1[1..2]; //risk path 1
dvar boolean z2[1..2]; //risk path 2

int A[1..30][1..41] =...; //incidence matrix

int u[1..30]=...; //source and destiny nodes

int H[1..2][1..41] =...; //risk links

int c[1..41] =...; // cost

dexpr int total = sum (p in 1..41) (x1[p]+x2[p]); //x1+x2

int cs = sum (p in 1..41) c[p]; // c

minimize (cs * (total) ); // c*(x1+x2)

subject to {

   forall (i in 1..30)
     sum (j in 1..41)
       A[i][j]*x1[j] == u[i];  //A*x1=u

   forall (i in 1..30)
     sum (j in 1..41)
       A[i][j]*x2[j] == u[i]; //A*x2=u

   forall (i in 1..2)
     sum (j in 1..41)
       H[i][j]*x1[j] - 41*z1[i] <= 0; //H*x1=41*z1

   forall (i in 1..2)
     sum (j in 1..41)
       H[i][j]*x2[j] - 41*z2[i] <= 0; //H*x2=41*z2 

   forall (i in 1..2)
     z1[i]+z2[i] <= 1; //z1+z2<=1

}
```

I expected the decision variables to be 0s and 1s showing the correct route yet the output is "No value"

Thank you.

**Engine log**

```
Warning:  Non-integral bounds for integer variables rounded.
Row 'c1' infeasible, all entries at implied bounds.
Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (0,04 ticks)
Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0,00 sec. (0,07 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 4 threads:
  Real time             =    0,00 sec. (0,00 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,00 sec. (0,07 ticks)
```

Comment: Where do you see this 'No value' output, exactly?  Is there any error or warning in the 'Problems' tab?  Can you provide the content of the 'Solutions' and 'Engine log' tabs?

Comment: The "No value" is the output of the decision variables in CPLEX in the "Problem Browser" section. I'm going to try to give you the output of the Solutions and Engine log tabs

Comment: The solutions tab is completely empty.

Answer (score 2):

One possible clue is in the output line:
**Row 'c1' infeasible**
which tells you that your model is infeasible. So it is not at all surprising that CPLEX can't find a value for your decision variables. Try to find where/why your model is infeasible.

Comment: Thanks I think I have more or less an idea where I think it's wrong.

Comment: The problem seems to be with restriction one, but I can't change that. It's the model. If I change the '=' sign to '<=' it gives back a solution.

Comment: So, what does the slightly relaxed solution look like? What is wrong with that solution? What happens if you keep the equality constraints but relax one of the other constraints? Have you saved the LP file from CPLEX and looked at the model that is generated? What happens when you try smaller problem instances than 30x41? Can you manually find a solution to check against the model?

Answer (score 0):

A clue as to why the model is infeasible may be in the warning `Non-integral bounds for integer variables rounded`.  Did you expect that the bounds of your integer variables are not all integers?

Comment: Since we're working with binary variables I assume they should all be integer values when added.

Comment: The problem seems to be with restriction one, but I can't change that. It's the model. If I change the '=' sign to '<=' it gives back a solution.